# Simply display RSS feed in/on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, rss, rss-reader

Maybe I am being a n00b here, but for the life of me, I cant find a simple drop in type solution for displaying an rss feed inside an aspx page?

I am looking for a simple solution, as when Firefox gets pointed to an rss feed, it just plainly displays it, no thrills, no fuss. I don't want to get into the xml and format it extensively. I just want a basic feed, will style it with font and a:styles. Thats it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I am attempting to show a worpress "feed" inside an aspx page...

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just display it in an iframe, browser will take care of the formating. Otherwise you'll need to parse the xml and create appropriate html tags for each of its elements and/or attributes.

Comment: Thanks, problem is each brwoser handles it differently, so I cant predict the results. FF and IE, both add their own unique twist to handle it with outlook etc.. and only then displays the rss. I jsut want the rss: heading + intro.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder i dont know the format of worpress "feed", but it doesn't change anything, you **will** have to parse it, and then eiher a) show only text content for heading and info, b) show heading and info exactly as they are in the file (with tags), c) style it yourself (by turning xml tags to html tags) - there may be a plugin that does that for you...